# Send email with php with php variables

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using a PHP script that send email with php variables (obtained by a form using POST method).
This is my code:

```
<?php
/* These will gather what the user has typed into the fieled. */

$nameField = $_POST['name'];
$emailField = $_POST['email'];
$questionField = $_POST['question'];

/* These are the variable that tell the subject of the email and where the email will be sent.*/

$emailSubject = 'Recupero password LightSchool';
$mailto = $_POST['email'];
$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';

/* This takes the information and lines it up the way you want it to be sent in the email. */

$body = '<br><hr><br> Name: '.$name.' <br> Email: '.$email.' <br> Question: '.$question.' <br>';

$headers = "From: $email\r\n"; // This takes the email and displays it as who this email is from.
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; // This tells the server to turn the coding into the text.
$success = mail($mailto, $emailSubject, $body, $headers); // This tells the server what to send.

?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
    <head>  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
    <title>MY Studenti</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>  
    <body style="background-image:url(http://studenti.lightschool.it/new/bkg.png)">  
    <div id="main">
    <h1>
    <img src="http://images.lightschool.it/logo/medium250x250.png" alt="" height="66" style="float: left; margin-right: 20px" width="62" />MY Studenti</h1>
    <p>Recupera password ti permette di recuperare la tua password, tramite 
    l'inserimento del tuo nome utente.</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="reset-pwd.php">
<table width="455" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="175" height="44" align="center"><label for"name">name</label></td>
    <td width="280"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" />
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="45" align="center"><label for="email">email</label></td>
    <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="41" align="center"><label for="question">question</label></td>
    <td><textarea name="question" cols="30" rows="5" id="question"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="38">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This PHP Script run successfully, but there are the three variables (name, email and question) that they won't showing into the sended e-mail.
I've tried with this also `var_dump($_POST['email']);` without solving.
How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

PS: I know there are a lots of this questions posted in this website and others, but nothing of these posted solution helped me.

Comment: You variables are `$nameField`, `$emailField` and `$questionField` and not what you declared in `$body`.

Comment: What if the person types malicious HTML code in one of your inputs?

Comment: @kingkero my inputs don't allow HTML code, so I think there's no problem. Anyway, what do you suggest?

Comment: @FrancescoSorge what do you mean by _don't allow_? If you write `<script>alert('im a bad boy');</script>` in the question textarea, you will receive an email that has this script inside. Maybe your email client already prevents this, but its better to be cautious

Comment: @FrancescoSorge thus you accepted exactly what I said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```php
$nameField = $_POST['name'];
$emailField = $_POST['email'];
$questionField = $_POST['question'];
```

to

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$question = $_POST['question'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling your Vars two different things. You want to be careful with this. If you're not filtering out anyone's email then someone could feed it a list of addresses and start sending out Spam from your box.

Comment: What do you suggest to prevent this?

Comment: You want to filter the user input and validate it. You can validate the email for example with:

filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Comment: You could do something simple like make sure it has one @ symbol, but not two. I've got a full write-up about the ways to stop spam on my blog from earlier this month: http://the-analytical.blogspot.com/2013/03/web-form-security-stopping-spam.html